# C# rounding with division

Tags: c#, math, algebra

This program calculates the amount of instances an event occurs within time.
The issue is that when I'm getting decimal numbers the program does not round how I want it to, for example: if i divide 7/5 i get 1, is it possible to get 2? the 'double' answer yields: 1.4.

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var kim = 7/5 ;
    Console.WriteLine(kim);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Any division I make I want it to round up.

For example: 7/5 = 1.4, but I want it to be 2; 5/2 = 2.5, but I want it to be 3, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`7/5` is an integer division. It will always round down. You will need a `double`/`decimal` division and [`Math.Ceiling`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.ceiling(v=vs.110).aspx) to round up:

```
Math.Ceiling(7.0 / 5.0);  // return 2.0
```

If your input values are `int`s, you will have to cast at least one of them to `double`

```
Math.Ceiling((double)7 / 5);
```

Comment: my variables yield me 7 and 5, how do i convert them into decimals?, 7 --> 7.0?

Comment: @AdanRamirez cast them. I added it to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Jakub said, you can use `Math.Ceiling`, or another option is to use the modulo. If the modulo is greater than 0, it means that there was some remainder and therefore you want to add 1, otherwise, you just add 0.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var kim = 7/5 + (7%5 > 0 ? 1 : 0);

    Console.WriteLine(kim);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```